# Is it a good idea to use a pipe to save data for the implementation of Heredoc?

Tags: c, redirect, pipe, heredoc

I'm trying to build my shell, so when I tried to implement Heredoc, I used the pipe as a file descriptor to redirect to the next command as grep, but my problem with this method is that the grep command gives me an error "Binary file (standard input) matches," implying that the pipe is a binary file. Please let me know if this is a possible option. Because I heard somewhere that bash uses pipes if the data is large.

This is my function where I read the heredoc input.

```
int redirecting_here_doc(int *fd, char *delimiter, int i, int exp)
{
    int pipefd[2];

    if (delimiter == NULL)
        return (-1);
    if (fd != 0 && (i - 1) > 0)
        close(fd[0]);
    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1)
        return (-1);
    if (read_here_document(pipefd[1], delimiter, exp) == 1)
        return (-1);
    if (fd != 0)
        fd[0] = dup(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

example:

cat <<lim | grep word ----> does not work

cat <<lim | grep -a word ------- > is fine

Comment: No, not a good idea for the reason you saw. Divert to a temp file. Redirect input from that

Comment: It's a possible option, but not necessarily a good one.  The binary data means you're doing something wrong.  A pipe has a finite buffer size — usually 64 KiB these days, but it used to be only 5 KiB and POSIX only guarantees 4 KiB, IIRC.  Thus, big here documents have the potential to cause problems.  Small here documents shouldn't be a problem.  Your examples are incomplete; they do not show the here document (which should be ended by a line containing only `lim`).  Your code is incomplete — please read about how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (aka [MCVE]).

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the grammar of your shell.